# Point Shiny fileInput to S3

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to put a Shiny app on AWS. I have a vast amount of data and multiple users would want to interact with this data without the need to add any external data.

For simplicity, let's assume the data is stored in flat files which I can upload on S3. I allow the user to read a file in through a `fileInput` button but when hosted on an AWS EC2 instance, it points to the local machine. Is there any way I can point it to the data on S3 and let the user upload one of those files into the shiny app?

Comment: perhaps with the RS3 pkg? https://github.com/Gastrograph/RS3

Comment: Thanks! That's an alternative I'm considering but the ideal case for me would be to get the file browsing and picking behaviour that `fileInput` offers.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your files rds;

before shinyUI(

```
rdsPath <- "your data path"
fileList <- dir(rdsPath, full.name = TRUE, pattern = ".rds") 
fileList <- setNames(lapply(fileList, function(x){x}),substr(fileList, 33, nchar(fileList)-4))
```

use select input in shinyUI(

selectInput("file",label = "file name:",multiple = F,choices = fileList,selected = fileList[[1]])

then in server.R you can call its path as:

```
input$file
```

Comment: This seems like a nifty work around but the flat files organisation is too complex for this to work.